# Kodi 17.0 (Krypton) on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I have found Kodi 17.0 (Krypton) in the Raspbian testing repository.
However, when I start it, it crashes with

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Crash report available at /home/pi/kodi_crashlog-20170226_234813.log
```

The crashlog starts like this:

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Sun Feb 26 23:13:31 CET 2017
 Kodi Options: 
 Arch: armv7l
 Kernel: Linux 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016
 Release: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
=====>  Core file: /home/pi/core (2017-02-26 23:13:30.991537995 +0100)
        =========================================
[New LWP 3514]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/kodi.bin'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x71374654 in nettle_yarrow256_update () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x6e766070 (LWP 3514)):
#0  0x71374654 in nettle_yarrow256_update () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6
#1  0x6eb7acdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-deb0.so.28
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
############# END STACK TRACE ###############
```

[At the Raspberry Pi Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=822286#p822286) somebody said that

> The upstream debian build of kodi will be a generic build with no raspberry pi support. E.g. it will try to use X and desktop OpenGL (rather than OpenGL ES). It won't work.
>
> You need a build built for raspberry pi (and that won't come from debian or raspbian).

Does it mean the testing will never work?

How come nobody wants to build this for Raspbian?

Comment: It will work, however efforts to make the software work on other devices (such as ARM on the raspberry pi) is done by volunteers, so It will work eventually!

The good news is that there is already a group that gives Raspberry pi Kodi support. I'd give [Xbian](http://www.xbian.org/73-2/) a go, they seem to keep things up to date with new Kodi releases. Although its not Rasbian, its still based on debian, and you can do all the other things you do on Rasbian, on this distro

Comment: But my understanding was that testing is just an autobuild that is not maintained by the Raspbian developers. And where can I see which packages are available in Xbian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is about getting a recent `Kodi` (rather than just about `testing`) There is an up-to-date repository for the Pi.

I am currently running:- `17.0 Git:20170202-523ece1-dirty Media Center Kodi`

Add the repo to your list of sources

```
echo 'deb http://pipplware.pplware.pt/pipplware/dists/jessie/main/binary /' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipplware_jessie.list
```

Add the repository’s key

```
wget -O - http://pipplware.pplware.pt/pipplware/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

NOTE this is an `ARM7` build

Answer (score 0):

Also on the topic of Kodi 17 they renamed tags in advancedsetting.xml

so if you had made changes to buffer settings there, you'll need to add the new tags:

<cachemembuffersize> renamed to <memorysize>

<readbufferfactor> renamed to <readfactor>

My advancedsetting.xml now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<advancedsettings>
        <network>
                <buffermode>3</buffermode>
                <cachemembuffersize>0</cachemembuffersize>
                <memorysize>0</memorysize>
                <readbufferfactor>4.0</readbufferfactor>
                <readfactor>4.0</readfactor>
        </network>
</advancedsettings>
```